# Where else are vim config files stored besides ~/.vimrc and /etc/vim?

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04

I somehow (a long time ago, probably playing around with [Rvim](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html#r-plugin-use)) made a keyboard shortcut which I now want to get rid of.

The problem is, I have no idea where the config file that has `nmap _ <-` is. Besides `/etc/vim/` and `~/.vimrc`, where (on Ubuntu) should I look to undo this change?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this bash command to find any vim related files:

```
    sudo find / -name *vim*
```

It will search all directories and return all files that contain vim in the name.

Comment: Thanks Alfonso. I got this error: `find: paths must precede expression: vimcat-0.png`

Answer (score 1):

`:scriptnames` tells you what scripts (including `.vimrc`'s) vim has loaded since startup.

---

I actually emailed the package author and he wrote back that in this case it's not listed as a `remap`, but rather RVim automatically uses `_` to write `<-`, *unless* you

```
cat >> ~/.vimrc
let vimrplugin_assign = 0
```

. So maybe I should have marked this as specifically a question about RVim.

Answer (score 1):

The `:verbose` command can tell you where a number of things within Vim have been set, including options and mappings. Try this:

```
:verbose map _
```

I should also note that it doesn't make sense to map underscore to the character sequence `<-` in normal mode.  Do you mean it's mapped to `<left>`, or is it actually an `imap`?

Comment: I'm not sure how he did it, but when you type `_` in insert mode (for example in the middle of a variable called `these_things_again`), it will write `these <- things <- again` instead.

Comment: That's an `imap`, not an `nmap`.  Regardless, the command in my answer should show you all mappings starting with _ and where they were set.

Comment: Cheers @Heptite!